# VBA For Each and With Block Object Variable or With Block Variable not set Error 91

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to use VBA to populate a HTML table in a webpage in Internet Explorer. I am using the following code to try and input one value; the fields have unique names:

```
Dim objShellWins As SHDocVw.ShellWindows
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim objDoc As Object

For Each objIE In objShellWins   'Look at IE & Windows Explorer objects in shell
    With objIE
        'Look for URL matching strURL
        If (InStr(1, .LocationURL, [URL], vbTextCompare)) Then
            Set objDoc = .Document
            If (InStr(1, objDoc.Title, [Title], vbTextCompare)) Then
                objDoc.getElementsByName([Name])(0).Value = "Value"
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next
```

I am getting Error 91: Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set on the objDoc.getElementsByName line, yet objDoc.Title returns the proper string. Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Comment: Choose debug and execute in Immediate window `? objDoc.getElementsByName([Name]).length` to check found nodes count.

Comment: Do you have a reference set to `Microsoft Internet Controls`?

Comment: Worth sharing relevant HTML if possible as well to make this more useful to future readers and aide in debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`objDoc` isn't the object variable causing the error. `getElementsByName` returns a `NodeList` object (a collection of `Nodes`) and `getElementByName(...)(0)` return a `Node` object. That's the object "variable" that's causing the error (very misleadingly as it's not a variable at all).

@omegastripes comment to check the `.length` property of the `NodeList` is the correct first step. Then I think you'll find that you either misspelled the name or there isn't an element with that name in the document.

Comment: Thanks, looks like that is the issue, there isn't an element with that name in the document when getElementsbyName is called.